# Gauss bonnet, positive curvature and genus!

Tags: differential-geometry

i have this basic question:

Why if we have a metric of non-negative curvature on compact surface then the genus of the surface  must be  $0$ or $1$? (i think we can use Gauss Bonnet)

thank you for any answer

Comment: Do you assume the curvature to be constant?

Comment: normally yes ! : ) @Sheve

Comment: By classification of surfaces, the Euler characteristic determines the surface.
So by Gauss Bonnet:
$$
\int_M K ds=2\pi\chi(M)
$$ 
Thus the Euler characteristic is non negative if and only if $K$ is 0 or 1 then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any assumption on constant curvature. If $K\ge 0$ everywhere, then $\int_S K\,dA \ge 0$, so $2\pi\chi(M)\ge 0$. This tells you $g=0$ or $g=1$.

Comment: thank you! : ).$